# Retrieving the first value from a number pair in parenthesis

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using jQuery to get the CSS transform property:

```
this.$slider.css('transform')
```

The following returns:

```
translate(100px, 0px)
```

How would I get just the number 100 as a variable using javascript or jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With javascript string functions:

```
str = this.$slider.css('transform');
a = str.substring(str.indexOf('(')+1,str.indexOf('px'));
alert(a); //100
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use regex:

`'translate(100px, 0px)'.match(/[^\(]+\(([0-9]+)/)[1]`

Comment: var currentTrans = this.$slider.css('transform');
   console.log(currentTrans.match(/[^\(]+\(([0-9]+)/)[1]);

returns an error "type error ... is null"

Comment: probably because there is no css transformation, you should check if match return an array `m = currentTrans.match(/[^(]+(([0-9]+)/); if (m) { m[0]; } else { /* no transform */ }`

Answer (score 1):

```
var transform = this.$slider.css('transform'),
    first = transform.split('(')[1].split('px')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

a small regex would suffice to just pull the first number, but note this isn't picky that they are pixel units or anything else that might come back in the CSS

```
this.$slider.css('transform').match(/\d+/)
```

Comment: that works well, except doesn't include if the number is negative

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "translate(100px,0px)"
parseInt(s.substring(s.indexOf("(")+1), 10) // returns 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take a slice starting at index 10, and send it through `parseInt`.

```
var str = this.$slider.css('transform');

var n = parseInt( str.slice(10), 10 );
```

Or if there will be other types of results than transform, you can do this:

```
var n = parseInt( str.split("(")[1], 10);
```